# How to resolve this fan trap in sql design

Tags: sql

I am having this 3 table, which is available Trip , country , and location. the relation in my ERD design is

Location | M-1 | Country | 1-M | Available Trip

This is my attempt for the resolution

```
create table country 
(
countryID int not null IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
countryName varchar(50), 
passportRegulation text, 
currency varchar(20),
)


 create table location
 (
locationID int not null IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
locationName varchar(100), 
countryID int references country(countryID)on delete cascade 
)

create table availableTrip
(
availableTripID int  not null IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
countryID int references country(countryID),
locationID int references location(locationID)
)
```

Is it possible to be correct if i having two foreign key to added into available trip , however i feel this is redundant because based on location i can know the country. I am kind of lost my direction for this design

Comment: Yes the LOCATON ref is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `countryId` needs to match the country in `locationId`, then you only want `locationId` in `availableTrip`.

You would look up the appropriate country using joins:

```
select avt.*, l.countryid
from availabletrip avt join
     location l
     on avt.locationid = l.locationid;
```

If the `countryId` could be different from the `locationId`, then you would want two columns.